# Select graph data to display using checkbox

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2003

I dont know if this can be done in excel or not. I tried to look around but could not find anything. Here is a simple example - There is a simple column graph for sales, expenditure and profits. There are different graphs for different offices - North America, Asia, Europe. Is there a way to have a single graph with check boxes for regions and the graph displays the data from the region check box selected

Answer (score 0):

The normal way is to have a large sheet with all the data and create a pivot table and chart. Excel allows you to choose a column as a "Report Filter".

First you have to unify all your data into one sheet

e.g.

Region | Month | Sales | Expenditure | Profits

Then create a pivot table or pivot chart based on that data. Move the Region field into the Report Filter area.